# Determine if a graph contains a triangle?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

This problem has an easy solution if our target time complexity is O(|V| * |E|) or O(V^3) and the like. However, my professor recently gave us an assignment with the problem statement being:

> Let G = (V, E) be a connected undirected graph. Write an algorithm that determines if G contains a triangle in O(|V| + |E|).

At this point, I'm stumped. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph) says:

> It is possible to test whether a graph with m edges is triangle-free in time O(m^1.41).

There was no mention of the possibility for a faster algorithm besides one that runs on a Quantum computer. I started resorting to better sources afterwards. A question on Math.SE linked me to [this paper](https://www-complexnetworks.lip6.fr/~latapy/Publis/triangles_short.pdf) that says:

> The fastest algorithm known for finding and counting triangles relies on fast matrix product and has an O(n^ω) time complexity, where ω < 2.376 is the fast matrix product exponent.

And that's where I started to realize that maybe, we're being tricked into working on an unsolved problem! That dastardly professor!

However, I'm still a bit skeptical. The paper says "finding and counting". Is that equivalent to the problem I'm trying to solve?

TL;DR: Am I being fooled, or am I overlooking something so trivial?

Comment: Are you sure it's `O(|V| + |E|)` and not `O(|V| * |E|)`?

Comment: @Mauris Yes. The problem statement itself (as given by my prof) could be wrong.

Comment: I would contact your prof about it. I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this in `O(|V| + |E|)`...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is an open problem.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Hope it helps.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Kindly note the edit I have made, it is important for the correctness.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun, the confusion in Wiki (and mentioned only slightly in the linked paper) is that the detection algo is O(m^1.41) for a _directed_ graph.

Comment: And the quadratic nature you found in checking pairs of nodes is actually because the edges can be quadratic on the number of vertices. This can be avoided by other representations as I had mentioned.

Comment: @user1952500 So you still think my solution is not O(V+E).

Comment: @user1952500 We both are defeating the purpose of this site if we do not discuss the conflict regarding the time complexity.

Comment: @user1952500 I can assure you that time complexity is O(V+E), but please give me a chance.

Comment: @Dante: A discussion is no good when you yell 'DON"T FOOL AROUND WITH ME' in caps followed by advise to drop my ego (wonder where that came from) and learn about time complexity. I don't discuss with rude people.

Comment: @user1952500 Please discuss the confilct at hand and let the users of this site gain from it.The time complexity is very important for algorithms.

Comment: @Dante, when you write in all-caps, it is meant to be yelling in social media.

Comment: @Dante, no worries. I already mentioned that I agreed with you in your solutions.

Comment: What is the complexity of the data structure used to store the graph? E.g. given a pair of nodes, can you test (in constant time) whether they are connected? If the graph is stored in a 'compressed' format based on storing cliques, then triangles can be checked in O(1) !

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It's not specified, but I guess you can assume the existence of adjacency lists.

Comment: If the list of edges was sorted you could "effectively" do this triangle check in |E| time with an array of length |V| of bitmasks of length |V|. Unfortunately, bitmask intersection-any "bitmaskA & bitmaskB > 0" operation would be considered O(|V|) instead of O(1).

Comment: I suggest making that a self-answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it turns out, this really isn't doable in O(|V| + |E|). Or at least, we don't know. I read 4 papers to reach this result. I stopped half-way into one of them, because I realized it was more focused on distributed computing than graph theory. One of them even gave probabilistic algorithms to determine triangle-freeness in "almost linear" time. The three relevant papers are:

- [Finding and counting given length cycles](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/ayz4.pdf) by Alon, Yuster & Zwick.
- [Testing Triangle-Freeness in General Graphs](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/tri.pdf) by Alon, Kaufman, Krivelevich & Ron.
- [Main-memory Triangle Computations for Very Large (Sparse (Power-Law)) Graphs](https://www-complexnetworks.lip6.fr/~latapy/Publis/triangles.pdf) by Latapy

I wrote about 2 pages of LaTeX for the assignment, quoting the papers with proper citations. The relevant statements in the papers are boxed:

---

[image]

---

In the end, I spoke to my professor and it turns out, it was in fact an unintended dire mistake. He then changed the required complexity to O(|V| * |E|). I don't blame him, he got me to learn more graph theory!

Comment: Kudos for posting the answer and resolution. Even if that - for the larger part - means "human error" :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for the O(|E|*|V|) version.

When you constrain |V| the bit mask intersect-any operation is effectively O(1) which gets you O(|E|), but that's cheating.

Realistically the complexity is O(|E| * (|V| / C)) where C is some architecture specific constant (i.e: 32, 64, 128).

```
function hasTriangle(v, e) {
  if(v.length > 32) throw Error("|V| too big, we can't pretend bit mask intersection is O(1) if |V| is too big!");
  // setup search Array
  var search = new Uint32Array(v.length);
  // loop through edges O(|E|)
  var lastEdge = [-1, -1];
  for(var i=0, l=e.length; i < l; i++) {
    var edge = e[i];
    if(edge[0] == lastEdge[0]) {
      search[lastEdge[1]] = search[lastEdge[1]] | (1 << edge[0]);
      search[edge[1]] = search[edge[1]] | (1 << edge[0]);
    } else {
      lastEdge = edge;
    }
    // bit mask intersection-any O(1), but unfortunately considered O(|V|)
    if( (search[edge[0]] & search[edge[1]]) > 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var V = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var E_no_triangle = [[0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5]];
var E_triangle = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]; // Triange(0, 2, 3)
console.log(hasTriangle(V, E_no_triangle)); // false
console.log(hasTriangle(V, E_triangle)); // true
```